# scala regex implementation

Tags: regex

I have the following string in input:

```
val str="11,FDESRTBGTY-DEDE-098-FDR,STR,5,1"
```

and I want to write a regex in scala to match it
I wrote the following code :

```
val regtest="""(11|12|13)(,+)(\S*)(,+)(\S*)(,+)(\d+)\)(,+)(\d+)\)""".r
stringin match {
      case regtest(num,comma1,name,comma2,typein,comma3,number1,comma4,number2) =>name + ","  + typein + ","  + "," + number2
      case _ => ""
}
```

I gt empty string result : `""`

Or the wanted result is rather:

```
val stringOut= "FDESRTBGTY-DEDE-098-FDR,STR,1"
```

any help with the please 
Regards

Comment: @Wiktor, yes I want to keep it

Comment: Good, then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does not match due to `\)`, remove them both. Your input string has no parentheses. Also, you want to use only 1 comma before the last number, and you want to get `number1`, not `number2` as the last value in the result:

```
val regtest="""(11|12|13)(,+)(\S*)(,+)(\S*)(,+)(\d+)(,+)(\d+)""".r
str match {
  case regtest(num,comma1,name,comma2,typein,comma3,number1,comma4,number2) =>println(s"${name},${typein},${number1}")
  case _ => ""
}
```

Note that probably `"""(1[123])(,)([^\s,]*)(,)([^\s,]*)(,)(\d+)(,)(\d+)""".r` would be a better pattern if you only allow 4 commas in the string and the 2nd and 3rd values can't contain commas. Also, note that `1[123]` is a more efficient and compact way to write `(?:11|12|13)`.

Alternatively, you may just remove the first and last comma-separated items in the string with

```
str.replaceAll("^[^,]+,|(,[^,]+),[^,]+$", "$1")
```

Here, `^[^,]+,` matches any 1+ chars other than `,` from the start of the string (`^`) and then a `,` or (`|`) a comma and 1+ non-comma chars are matched and captured into Group 1 (with `(,[^,]+)`) and then the last `,` and 1+ non-comma chars at the end of the string (`[^,]+$`) are matched. All matched text is removed and the capture group value is pasted back into the result with the `$1` placeholder.

See the [Scala demo](http://rextester.com/TVRCA56824).